# How to refres servlet data by refreshing a browser - spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, refresh

How can I in my controller refresh data stored in attribute by refreshing a browser ?
what exacly i want to do:
im donwloding some json data and then im displaying it in my site.
its changing every second so i want it when i refresh page to update.
here how my controller metod looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String infoWeather(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest req) {
        Location location = LocationManager.getLocation(req);
        model.addAttribute("location", location);
        Weather weather = WeatherManager.getWeather(location);
        model.addAttribute("weather", weather);
    return "index";
}
```

What it does ?

```
LocationManager.getLocation(req)
```

is getting the location depending on users ip

```
WeatherManager.getWeather(location)
```

and weathermanager get the weather for ur location
im displaying it in my site

but when i refresh it doesnt update the weather data wich i parse from json cointain also the date (year, mont, day, hours, minutes, and seconds)
so it always show the data from the first time i enter the page after running my servlet

please give me some simple examples

Comment: Are you sure that WeatherManager.getWeather returns correct value for second call?

Comment: here is from where i get mt data
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=51.1&lon=17.0333&lang=en i think yes becous no metter how long i w8 it always show me the time from my first entry after servlet start

Comment: Em, request to this page always returns same value. In fact response will be changed sometime (when weather is changed LOL)